# Google Drive API (GTL) - Create multiple folder paths in order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

I'm using the [Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) (GTL) to access the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

According to it's [Introduction to the Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction),

> Query execution by the service is inherently asynchronous.

Which means when you try to create a path like: `root/a/b/c`, before you can create folder `b`, you'll have to:

1. Make sure `a` is created, if not, create it before `b` was trying to check it's `parentRef`.
2. Know the `id` of folder `a` so you can create `b` in it.

And same goes to `c`.

I use something like the following to get the `id` of a folder by name within a known parent folder id:

```
    // Get parentID by name "parent".

    let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForChildrenListWithFolderId(parentID)
    query.q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '\(parentID)' in parents and trashed=false and title='\(name)'"

    query.maxResults = 1

    GTLFileTicket = GTLDriveService.executeQuery(
        query,
        completionHandler: {(
            ticket:         GTLServiceTicket!,
            object:         AnyObject!,
            error:          NSError!) -> Void in

            // Callback
            self.GTLFileTicket = nil
            if error == nil {
                // Get the id from the object. If nil make another query to create a folder named "name" within folder "parentID".
            } else {
                // error handles here.
            }
    })
```

In the other part of the project, I called the above method within a for loop:

```
var parent = "root"
for item in array {
    createFolderIfNotExisted(item, parent: parent)
    parent = item
}
```

Apparently, it will fail and end up creating only the first folder as the 2nd query starts before the 1st query even finished. I googled around but didn't see a way to make it synchronous calls instead. (Tho I saw Java API branch can have something like `.await()`?)

Is there a way to make sure the calls can be executed in sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using a synchronous for loop. The createFolder function should call back when it's complete; that callback should start the next loop iteration.

Comment: So how do you do it to create series of child folder and avoid the racing issue? Set up a global `[String]` and do it one by one within the callback block?

Comment: The array doesn't need to be global; it will be captured by the callback blocks.

Comment: I see, I'll give it a try then.